# Why is IF failing with satl state file from Jenkins?

Tags: salt

I invoke a saltstack state file "init.sls" from a Jenkins pipeline as below. If `job == Yes`, it is expected to execute `test_command` and test_final, else `if job == No`, it must execute `test2_command` and `test_final`

```
{% if {{ job }} == 'Yes' %}
test_command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "TEST COMMAND EXEC"
{% elif {{ job }} == 'No' %}
test2_command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "TEST2 COMMAND EXEC"
{% endif %}

test_final:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "FINAL SUCCESS"
```

However it is not successful. Is there a better way to achieve using salt state execution?

Comment: You may want to describe what `is not successful` means.

Comment: [Pipeline] 
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:projects.test' failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token ':', got '}'; line 4

---
{% if {{ job }} == 'Yes' %}    <======================
test_command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo \"TEST IF COMMAND EXEC\"
{% elif {{ job }} == 'No' %}
dpio_command:
[...]
---"}}]
[Pipeline] }

Answer (score 1):

The jinja syntax error is caused by the `{{` around your `job` var.
Those curly braces are not required as you are already inside jinja block, noted by the `{%`.

So to get your code working just replace  your `{{ job }}` by `job`.
This should be working.